# I can't run my first app with Flutter after run I get this error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4UAr.png)
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\untitledflt\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\karim.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Adapt the subject please, try to make a better subject  as it tells us nothing.

Comment: just run your terminal next command  `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then `flutter run` or run your app

Comment: please provide a screenshot for us to figure it out

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil  not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is worked after remove "debug.keystore" files and bulid project